# Scrolling overlay in safari not smooth as in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, scroll, safari

I have a web page (a single article). When I open it in `Apple Safari` browser and try to scroll there are some flaws (it was not scrolling smoothly). When I try to scroll the same page in `Google Chrome` browser it scrolls smoothly.

What can be the reason for that?

Link to `URL` of the page is bellow:

url: http://www.apfelblatt.de/2015/08/01/apple-watch-werbungen-werden-im-tv-ausgestrahlt/

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're asking? Is this a page you've created? If you're a user having trouble with someone else's webpage, Stack Overflow is probably not the best venue for asking about that.

Comment: yes, i have this page created

Comment: It's scrolling smoothly in Chrome for me, at least once everything's loaded. Maybe if you describe what you did to create the page, someone else can help you. I'm sorry, but I don't know what's wrong here.

Comment: in safari it is not scrolling smoothly... in chrome ist scrolling by me, too!

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood what you said.